# Zend_Http_Client::PUT not working

Tags: zend-framework, rest

Am trying to update my record via the PUT method

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::PUT);
$client->setUri('http://example.com/api/type/');
$client->setParameterPost(array(                
    'useremail'  => '*****@****.***',
    'apikey'   => 'secretkey',
    'expenseid' => '4',
    'description' => 'TEST WEB API',
    'amount'   => '5000.00',
));
```

However it does not seem to work.The same also applies to **Zend_Http_Client::DELETE**.
It seems only **Zend_Http_Client::POST** and **Zend_Http_Client::GET** are working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Zend Framework's implementation yet, but you may want to check that you have Apache configured to allow PUT and DELETE requests.

Assuming that you are using virtual hosts and userdirs, see the following file:
`.../apache/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

In that file make sure that you have `PUT` and `DELETE` in the list of allowed HTTP methods for your directory.

```
<Directory ".../path-to-your-vhost-directory-here">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    <Limit HEAD GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept HEAD GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

**Edit:**
you can find the official documentation for the  directive here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit